# Extract amplitude and phase using scipy fft (fast fourier transform)

Tags: python, scipy

I am trying to use a Fast Fourier Transform to extract the amplitude and phase shift of two sinusoidal waves. By experimenting, I found out that transform returned from the FFT had an amplitude that was actually an N/2 times multiple of my actual signal (where N is the number of samples in the wave). So, to extract and plot the actual transform, I had to multiply the gain by 2/N.

The portion of the code showing this is attached below:

```
from scipy.fft import fft, rfft
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 600  # number of sample points
d = 1.0  # time domain
f = 50   # frequency
u = 0.1  # mean inlet velocity
du = 0.1  # velocity perturbation rate
T = 1.0 / f  # period
s = d/N  # sample spacing

# 1st sine wave
x1 = np.linspace(0.0, d, N)
y1 = u*du* np.sin(f * 2.0*np.pi*x1)
yf1 = rfft(y1)
xf1 = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*s), N//2)

# 2nd sine wave
q = 0.08  
dq = 0.1  
phi = np.pi / 2 # phase delay (rad)

x2 = np.linspace(0.0, d, N)
y2 = q*dq* np.sin(f * 2.0*np.pi*x2 - phi)
yf2 = fft(y2)
xf2 = np.linspace(0.0, 1.0/(2.0*s), N//2)

#plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(xf1, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf1[0:N//2]))
plt.plot(xf2, 2.0/N * np.abs(yf2[0:N//2]))
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

I cannot figure out why the FFT returns this amplitude multiplied by N/2.

A secondary problem I face is how to extract the phase shift (phi) from the 2 transformed waves. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The `2/N` scaling is due to the particular FFT definition used. It can be defined with or without a normalizing factor (`sqrt(N)`) if it is important to have the same energy in the time domain and frequency domain signal or not. The phase of the signal is given by the complex number that describes the frequency content. If you write the complex number using polar coordinates, you will see the (relative) phase of each, The difference of these describe the phase difference. Is this what you mean by "phase shift"?

Comment: The normalization factor you are referring to (sqrt(N), should be introduced in the time domain function?
```
y1 = sqrt(u*du* np.sin(f * 2.0*np.pi*x1))
```
Then perform the FFT of the reduced y1 function?

Comment: It depends on which signal is the "original" one. If you have a time domain signal that you want to convert to the frequency domain, I would say that the logical thing is to scale the frequency domain signal to have the same energy as the time domain signal, thus scaling _after_ (or possible _during_) the transform.

Comment: Thanks @JohanL, I now realize that scaling is necessary. I had the impression that the FFT function would perform the scaling (normalize), so the frequency domain signal would have the same energy as the time domain

Comment: The FFT can be defined with or without the scaling. If there is no scaling in the FFT, there is typically "double" scaling in the IFFT so that `x == IFFT(FFT(x))`.